# Any way to pre-compile pyarrow?

Tags: cython, pyarrow

I have freshly installed pyarrow library in my virtualenv.

The first time I `import pyarrow as pa` it takes a very long time.

Then, after importing, the first time I instantiate a `Table` it takes a very long time. Subsequent Table instantiations are lightning fast however.

If I quit my python shell and re-open it... now the pyarrow import is also fast, and first instantiation is also fast.

I assume that is because it was having to compile stuff the first time the modules are imported, but having done that once they are cached in my venv.

I can see [in the src](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/main/python/pyarrow/) there are loads of .pyx and .pyd files, which I believe are Cython.

I want to deploy an app using pyarrow, either as AWS Lambda function or in a Docker container.

So I want to ensure that the library is fully pre-compiled, already in the artefacts that are deployed, before running the app. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

These pyx/pyd files are compiled at install time (or before if you are installing from a binary wheel). Calling `import pyarrow` doesn't do any cython compilation.

The reason it is faster the 2nd time is either because some **pycache** was created the first time or because the second time the OS is faster are reading all the different files.

You can try adding `RUN python -c "import pyarrow;pyarrow.table({})` to your Dockerfile, but I doubt it will help at run time.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really look for a solution more than an explanation though

Comment: Well, if it's generating the .pyc files into `__pycache__` that is taking the time then it seems like the tip on p20 re running `compileall` is what I need https://ep2020.europython.eu/media/conference/slides/CeKGczx-best-practices-for-production-ready-docker-packaging.pdf